# Как создать массив различных типов

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели, типы-данных

Необходимо создать массив, в который можно добавлять данные различных типов(как в python).
Предполагаю, что надо использовать массив указателей и шаблоны, но не знаю как связать все воедино.

Comment: Можно хранить как массив указателей на char.

Comment: *"Необходимо создать массив, в который можно добавлять данные различных типов"* Зачем? [XY-проблема](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710/215103)?

Comment: В лоб решение - сделать массив универсальных сырых указателей (void*), но работать с такими указателями надо осторожно. По сути вы получите ровно то, что хотите, но в целом это вряд ли хорошее решение

Comment: Под капотом таких списков, как правило, создаётся что-то типа vector-а для каждого отдельного типа данных в духе `map<type_mark, vector<type>>`. Но это правда не такая уж простая реализация.

Comment: Массив `any`, например. Но вслед за HolyBlackCat - зачем вам такой геморрой?...

Comment: В python нет (встроенных) массивов. Во встроенных контейнерах, тех же списках, хранятся ссылки на объекты, а не данные различных типов. Если хотите что-то похожее, то используйте `::std::vector<::std::shared_ptr<::std::any>>`. Но скорее всего вам это не нужно.